# Как поменять цвет Foreground TreeViewItem при выделении?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть `TreeView`. Выделяю в нем `TreeViewitem`. `TreeViewItem` подсвечивается зелёным. А цвет текста становится белым. Как поменять цвет текста на другой и как сделать, чтобы при наведении цвет `TreeViewItem` тоже менялся?

```
treeView.Resources.Clear();
treeView.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime));
treeView.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime));
treeView.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrush, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime));
treeView.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightColor, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lime));
```

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, вы все делаете верно. Попробуйте переопределять системные цвета подсветки в XAML

```
<TreeView.Resources>                                                
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
        Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
        Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
        Color="Blue" />
</TreeView.Resources>
```